# Test interstitial ads not showing. Error code 3- no fill

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

So i want to implement a interstitial ad into my app. I am starting testing with the test ads and they don't work. I get error code 3 from onAdFailedToLoad() method.Also i've tried showing an interstitial from this example and it didn't work aswell https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples. I tried to run it from a nougat os btw

Here is my code:

The setupAds()method is called in onCreate()

```
private void setupAds() {


    //MobileAds.initialize(this, "AD_ID");

    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "AD_ID");

    mInterstitial=new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("AD_ID");

    mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this, "onAdlOOADED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

            Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this, "onAdfailedtoload" + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this, "onAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this, "onAdleftaplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this, "onAdcLOASED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().
            addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mInterstitial.loadAd(request);

    ((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.test_ad_button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitial.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And i show the ad here :

```
if (!isFirstStarted()){
            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitial.show();
            }
        }
```

And here is a snippet of the manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="ID"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure your App ID is same inside `AndroidManifest` and at the time of MobileAdSDK initialization

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me !

**Note :** In this example i used testing ads id and testing interstitial id.

```
MobileAds.initialize(LoginActivity.this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(LoginActivity.this);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build());

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                super.onAdLoaded();

            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry but this is the same code as mine but you launch the ad when is loaded

Comment: try it first , then we can find other solution !

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) . 
`ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL` : The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Answer (score 0):

The **errorCode 3** means that AdMob cannot fulfill your AD request.

According to the [document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdFailedToLoad(int)) of **onAdFailedToLoad()** method, there are 4 types of error.

**errorCode 0**: ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR - Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.

**errorCode 1**: ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST - The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.

**errorCode 2**: ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR - The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.

**errorCode 3**: ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL - The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory. According to the [AdMob Help Community](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en), a policy violation also leads to **errorCode 3**.

**Case 1** only happens by a careless developer. It should not happen. It is not user trigger-able.

**Case 2** occurs when a user uses an AD-blocker or network connection is down. It is user trigger-able.

**Case 0**, **case 2** and **case 3** are not controllable by developers. I suggest that you need to deal with these cases in your app.